# Lowercase<-->Uppercase Function Not Working As Planned

Tags: c, bitmask

So, what I'm trying to do is create a function that switches uppercase characters to lowercase and vice-versa.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int caplowswitch(char string[], char switched[]);

int main(){

    char name[] = "whyisthisnotworking";
    char flipped[] = "";

    caplowswitch(name, flipped);


return 0;
}

int caplowswitch(char word[], char switched[]){

    char *ptrword = word;
    unsigned short int counter = 0;

    printf("Your text input is: %s \n", word);

    while(*ptrword != NULL){

    switched[counter] = (*ptrword ^ 0x20);
    counter++;
    ptrword++;

    }

    printf("Your flipped text is: %s \n", switched);

    return 1;
}
```

In the process of learning. Thanks for your time.

Comment: And this doesn't work... how? should we just guess what the problem is? We're here to help, not be your debuggers.

Comment: Where do the characters you put "into" *switched* end up?  (Hint: Not in the array switched/flipped, since that's only one character long.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot to add null termination to `switched`. You need to add

   ```
   switched[counter] = '\0';  // add '\0' to the end
   ```

   before

   ```
   printf("Your flipped text is: %s \n", switched);
   ```
2. You need to change `while(*ptrword != NULL)` to `while(*ptrword != '\0')`.
3. As @ooga pointed out, you'd better allocate enough space to `flipped`. So change `char flipped[] = "";` to `char flipped[100] = "";`.

After fixing these issues, it should work as expected. Check out running result on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/XwOnLn).

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed that haha

Comment: Don't forget the other important points, like not allocating enough memory to `flipped` and the mistake of using `NULL` where you mean `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving enough space to `flipped`. By defining and initializing it as:

```
char flipped[] = "";
```

you are only giving it a single character, initialized to `'\0'`, since that form of definition allocates only enough space to hold the given string, and you've passed the empty string.
Try

```
char flipped[100] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three mistakes in your code.

Point1:

Never `char flipped[] = "";` allocate memory like this. This is not an proper procedure.

Point2:

Dont check null character like this `while(*ptrword != NULL)`. You should check like while(*ptrword != '\0') this.

Point3:

null termination is required for `switched`. So after `while(*ptrword != NULL) { ...}  set switched[counter]='\0'`